# What will happen if I connected 3amps adapter to motor that's need only 2.1amps are that will burning the motor?

Tags: power-supply, current, motor, stepper-motor

I have 3amps power supply and the motor just need 2.1amps so if I connected they together are that will destroying the motor ?

Comment: A 12V 1A (12W) light will draw only 1A even if I connect it to a car battery with a 700A cold cranking capacity, it's no different with a motor, provided the supply voltage is more or less the same at the voltage the load needs then the load will draw only the current it needs. Those ratings are the maximum allowable outputs that the supply is *capable* of generating, the supply will not *force* that current into a load. Don't worry, as long at the voltage ratings match (and the supply is capable of handling the current) your motor will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the voltage of your power supply is equal to the voltage required by your motor, then the supply will only output the amperage needed by the motor. If the motor needs 2.1 amps then that is what the supply will deliver. In general, power supplies output the current demanded by the load and not their maximum current rating.  It is important to match the voltage ratings, however, or the load could be damaged.

Answer (score 0):

Much more important is the VOLTAGE of the source vs. the rating of the load (motor, or whatever).  START with the most important factors and work your way down the priority list.  A load will NOT draw more power than it needs, regardless of how much power is available from the supply.