# Should brushed DC motors run hot?

Tags: motor, dc

After running my motor for 15 minutes, the body of the motor becomes very hot and I can only keep my finger on the spindle shaft for about two seconds.

I'm using a Mean Well 48 V 7.3 A 350.4 W power supply, connected to a 6-90 VDC 20 A 1200 W motor controller, connected to a 48 V 350 W brushed DC motor.
the attached drawing depicts my interpretation of where ammeter probes should be placed to measure current when the motor is running. It is correct?
[image]
One of the motor specifications is *continuous torque max in-oz 150*  (1.1 [N·m](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton-metre)) and 1 A = 28.3 in-oz (0.2 N·m). I want to run the motor at 140 in-oz (1.0 N·m), so it requires 4.98 A.

Since the power supply outputs 7.3 A, could that extra 2.32 A be the reason the motor gets so hot?

Comment: If the motor is significantly hotter than you expect, are you sure there isn't a *mechanical* problem? If the shaft in particular is what's getting so hot, I would wonder if there's a failed or misaligned bearing--with electrical problems I would expect the heat to concentrate in either the rotor or armature winding, only making it down to the shaft relatively slowly. You woudln't happen to have an IR thermometer to measure with, would you?

Comment: No load speed is directly proportional to voltage input. Mechanical power dissipated as heat in the bushings or bearings, due to rotational damping, will increase as the square of the speed. Even if the bearings are in good operating condition the hot shaft may be due to power dissipation when the motor runs at maximum rated voltage and therefore maximum no load speed. If motor performs up to ratings the no load current should be below the specified value for producing maximum torque. If you put a mechanical break on the motor to reduce shaft speed torque/current increase as speed decreases.

Comment: What's the motor current under these (no load) conditions?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/241998/what-will-happen-if-i-connected-3amps-adapter-to-motor-thats-need-only-2-1amps

Comment: In the comment above I should have said "maximum continuous torque" because the motor makes maximum torque at stall (zero) speed when maximum rated voltage is applied. The no load torque should be less than the maximum continuous torque rating of the motor provided the motor bearing or bushing is in good operating condition.

Comment: Does the motor controller have an output to say how much current it is supplying? Does the motor specification say it needs additional cooling under some circumstances?

Comment: Does the motor have any self-cooling provision or specs? Some integrate a fan  driven by the same shaft (often those that are designed to run continuously at a decent speed) but whether there's a fan or just vents, airflow is needed. Some motors in this power  class (for electric bikes) have cooling fins on the housing, to be cooled by the airflow from moving along; they can get pretty hot labouring uphill at low speed

Answer (score 6):

Motor winding wire is available with several temperature ratings. Class A - 105 °C, Class B - 130 °C, Class F - 155 °C and Class H - 180 °C. Class A is rarely if ever used and Class B isn't used a lot either. The motor frame and shaft will not be nearly as hot as the hottest point in the windings, but you can see that the frame and shaft could get pretty hot. It is difficult to judge whether the motor is running within spec by touching the motor.

You should measure the current. If the current does not exceed the rated value, the motor is probably ok. If the shaft and bearing ares is the hottest part of the motor, you may have a bearing problem. If the motor is driving the load through a belt, the side load on the shaft may be too high. If the shaft is coupled to the load shaft, check alignment.

In my answer to another question or yours, I mentioned the reduction of motor self cooling capability when operating at reduced speed.

Comment: The motor was running with no load. I was testing the new Mean Well and motor controller. Previously the motor, powered by a 19VDC 3.4A wall wart, ran for a 1/2 hour with no load and only got slightly warm.

Comment: Running much hotter with no load than previously observed certainly indicates some kind of problem. A bearing has already been mentioned. Another possibility is shorted armature winding turns. You can not effectively diagnose the problem without an ammeter.

Comment: My  VELLEMAN DVM850BL measures DC voltage from 200mV to 600V and DC current from 200uA to 10A. Would that be sufficient? If so how is diagnoses accomplished?

Comment: I would measure the no-load current as you have the motor connected now, but that might exceed the 10A rating of the meter. Perhaps the first thing to do is to use an ohmmeter to check from any commutator segment to the shaft to see if a winding has shorted to the rotor core. Then you could check the resistance between every commutator segment and the adjacent segment. However that might be difficult because a lot of ohmmeters don't accurately measure really low resistance. You could also try measuring between every segment and the diametrically opposite segment -- or brush to brush.

Comment: Another thing that you could do is turn the shaft by hand and try to determine if turns as easily as it should and if there is any sound from the bearings.

Comment: The degree symbol (°) can be copy-pasted from [here](https://pmortensen.eu/world/FixedStrings.php) (e.g., selection by Shift + Alt + D or some TABbing). It has Ω and µ as well.

Comment: Thank you @Peter Mortensen

Answer (score 5):

> *Since the power supply outputs 7.3A....*

It only outputs that current when demanded by the load. It doesn't output 7.3 amps continuously else, if you disconnected the load, the output voltage would rise to infinity in order to sustain the 7.3 amps. The 7.3 amps figure is the *maximum* output current of the power supply.

You motor gets warm because it is not 100% power efficient. It may still be running within specification even though it feels quite hot.

Comment: Also note that the 7.3 amp figure isn't even relevant, since there's a switching converter between the 7.3 amp power supply and the motor. Depending on the voltage the motor runs at, the actual motor current could even be higher than 7.3 amps.

Comment: The devil will be in the details.

Answer (score 2):

When the motor shaft is coupled to the equivalent mechanical load an equation holds where the torque in the motor air gap equals the torque in the equivalent load at each point in time:

$$T{_m} = T{_L}$$

Motor torque in the air gap is torque constant times current in motor coils:

$$T{_m} = k{_T}I{_m}$$

Load torque is a dynamic differential equation which depends on equivalent rotational inertia (J) "seen by" the motor shaft (perhaps reflected through a gearbox), on the instantaneous change in shaft speed, on the equivalent rotational damping (D) seen by the motor shaft, and on the motor shaft speed (omega):

$$T{_L} =J{_E}\frac{d{\omega}}{dt}+D{_E}{\omega}$$

The dynamic equation for finding an operating point:

$$k{_T}I{_m}=J{_E}\frac{d{\omega}}{dt}+D{_E}{\omega}$$

These equations will have conversion factors (numbers) inserted unless one uses the coherent SI units to specify all variables. So this discussion assumes all units are converted to coherent SI units where electrical power and mechanical power are given in Joules per second (Watt) and torque is given in Newton-meter.

The steady state equilibrium condition is given when the motor makes just enough torque to overcome the heat loss to rotational friction and there is zero rotational acceleration:

$$k{_T}I{_m} = D{_E}{\omega}$$

The electrical heat dissipation in the motor is caused by the current flowing through the coil resistance where higher current is necessary to the effort to accelerate a large equivalent rotational inertia in a short period of time and to overcome the heat dissipation due to mechanical friction at angular shaft speed(s). The characteristics of the mechanical load usually dominate the design effort to properly size and operate the power source, controller, and PMDC motor.

Typical when a reduction gearbox or drive-line couples the motor to the load this becomes part of the equivalent mechanical load. Even though the gear drive has rotational inertia it often is used to match equivalent rotational inertia to the characteristics of the mechanical power source at some operating speed but this also tends to increase the equivalent mechanical damping.

Comment: I made a drawing depicting my interpretation of where  ammeter probes should be placed to measure amperage when the motor is running. How can it be placed in a comment?

Comment: I just added the drawing to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state the exact type of motor.

There are quite a few motors that don't like running without neither a load nor a rev limiter.

In particular, you can overheat and/or mechanically break a "series field" motor by just leaving it powered, even well below the rated voltage. It just spins at higher and higher rpm and either outright breaks, or runs steady at rpm that wears brushes and bearings pretty quick.

Comment: It is a brushed permanent magnet DC motor. Thinking it might be bearing misalignment, I removed the end caps that position the ball bearings. I rotated the end caps until I got the easiest spindle rotation by my fingers. It still requires hard finger pressure to rotate the spindle. After running it for 15 minutes the spindle got so hot that I could only keep my finger on it for about one second. The ammeter measurement will be done tomorrow.

Comment: The ammeter test result, with no load, was 2.8 amps.  The amps increased to 3.2 amps when I  applied a load, using my fingers, trying hard to stop the spindle.                      
The power supply can output 7.3 amps. The motor spec.s list max torque of 150 IN-OZ at 5.3 amps. Does the low ammeter result indicate a problem? Could it be related to the, very stiff, hard to manually rotate spindle?

Comment: I pulled the rotor out of the frame. There is no apparent damage to the windings. I reassembled the motor minus the frame and everything rotates freely and smoothly.

Comment: There is also no sign that the rotor is rubbing against the magnets. Seems the only causes left are bearing misalignment when end caps are bolted to the frame, or do the ammeter results indicate some other problem?

Comment: I was hoping someone would say the ammeter results are  reason for the problem. I have a small machine shop that includes a granite surface plate and precision measuring instruments. The assembly will be set up between centers, on the surface plate, and concentricity of component locating diameters will be measured.

Comment: The axes of the end cap I.D, that houses the brushes and accepts a spindle bearing, is off axis, with the end cap I.D that engages the frame O.D., by .011". I will turn the end cap O.D. that engages the frame.

Comment: First, permanent magnet motors don't suffer from the problem I described. Second, the 2.8 ampere no-load reading is not low, it is rather high. Electric motors should not waste almost half of their rated power just for spinning with no load. Values like 5-15% are expected. High friction, misaligned brushes, shorted rotor windings or just common low build quality may be the culprit.

Comment: The air gap is only .022 so I decided not to turn the end cap O.D.. I've reassembled everything minus the brush assembly and, while it doesn't rotate freely, it takes much less force to rotate manually. The magnets are incredibly strong. Wouldn't that cause some resistance when rotating the spindle manually?

Comment: One final thought on the hot motor…I didn’t mention the motor label is marked PM57-24-28-3000-BL01 3000 MAX RPM, 150 oz-in.  and  the spec. sheet lists BACK EMF CONSTANT (Ke) V/K R.P.M. 20.8. 
So wanting to run the motor at approx. 2200rpm led to the following calculation (1000rpm / 20.8V = 0.0208V * 2200rpm = 45.76V), which is the reason for using a 48VDC power supply. Did I misunderstand something and buy too powerful a motor?